# how to fix error when authenticating in U1

Tags: 11.10, ubuntu-one, login

Like other users, when authenticating in U1 I get this error:

```
Method "CreateItem" with signature "a{sv}(oayay)b" on interface "org.freedesktop.Secret.Collection" doesn't exist.
```

And in `/var/log/auth.log`:

```
gnome-keyring-daemon[4793]: egg_symkey_generate_simple: assertion `iterations >= 1' failed
gnome-keyring-daemon[4793]: couldn't prepare to write out keyring: /home/yann/.gnome2/keyrings/login_1.keyring
```

So I tried to move "login.keyring". I typed no password for the security when logging into U1, accepted non secured way to save passwords. And a message told me the operation successfully completed (in French).
But, sync did not work.

And `u1sdtool --status` returned this:

```
State: AUTH_FAILED
    connection: With User With Network
    description: auth failed
    is_connected: False
    is_error: True
    is_online: False
    queues: WORKING
```

I'm sorry U1 doesn't work anymore; it was really useful to me.
Can you help me ?

Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

If you see the message "Method "CreateItem" with signature "a{sv}(oayay)b" on interface "org.freedesktop.Secret.Collection" doesn't exist" now in Oneiric, this is gnome-keyring bug:
 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-keyring/+bug/874501

This is fixed in gnome-keyring - 3.2.2-0ubuntu0.1 .
You can run the following command in a Terminal to see which version you have installed:

```
apt-cache policy gnome-keyring
```

If you are running Ubuntu 11.10 and do not have the latest version of gnome-keyring open the Software Center and check **Edit > Software Sources**. In the updates tab make sure you have 'Recommended Updates (Oneiric-updates)' checked. Then run your updates from the Update Manager.